# Count the nodes created in the past 24 hours, 7 days, 30 days, and 365 days

Tags: 7, views

I want to count the number of nodes created in the past 24 hours, 7 days, 30 days, and 365 days. I have used the Statistics module, but it isn't working.

I will not pass the year in the URL. So I don't want to use contextual filter method here.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your time base is now - delta and not midnight - delta, you can use the offset format in a date criteria.  E.g. -24 hours  or -30 days.  I use this to display recent articles all the time.

Not sure if you can pass an offset as a contextual filter.  But shouldn't be a problem to create sub views with different criteria and use a menu to select which one you want.

If you are looking for midnight based stats, you'll probably have to write your own view filter.

Also, I assume you know you'll have to use aggregation to get the counts.

Comment: Can I show all the content will 4 results in the same view ?

Comment: You could do that using attachment views. Separate views for each range attached to the display view.  Alternatively, you could have each view as a block and lay them out on a node as needed.

Comment: Is that a efficient way to use 4 attachments ?

Comment: No matter how you do it, code or views you will need to do 4 queries to gather the data using SQL aggregation.  There is no single query will get what you want.  As to performance, four aggregate queries are not that much of a load plus this information can be cached so that the queries are only run occasionally.  This can be done via the views settings.